# Возможно ли подружить node.js и АТОЛ?

Tags: node.js, сервер, печать

Задача:
Есть сайт, он отправляет запрос на локальный IP, на котором я хочу разместить сервер на node. Node принимает запрос и печатает чек через фискальный регистратор АТОЛ. Тот в свою очередь имеет подключение inthernet т.е. виден в локальной сети.
Такое возможно?

Comment: Почему бы и нет, в чем вы видите проблему?

Comment: https://integration.atol.ru/api/ и https://app.swaggerhub.com/apis-docs/atol-dev/fptr-web-server/10.9.2.3